# How to infer Record keys based on array got as argument

Tags: typescript

How can this be implemented with types?

```
const createConstants = (...keys) => {
  let record = {};
  keys.forEach(key => {
    record[key] = key;
  });
  return record;
};
```

Comment: Not possible unless the keys are known prior to the program running. Otherwise, the type of record should just be `Record<string, string>`

Comment: @smac89 would it be possible defining something like <T extends string> for the keys?

Comment: Indeed you can do `function createConstants<T extends string>(keys: T[]): Record<T, T> {...}`, but if the array is just strings, why not just use string instead of `T extends string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of [Variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) you can infer each element in the array/tuple.
I mean, you can infer all arguments in exact order, smth like this: `["a", "b", "c"]` instead of `('a'|'b'|'c')[]`.
Consider this example:

```js
const createConstants = <
    K extends string,
    Keys extends K[]
>(...keys: [...Keys]) =>
    keys.reduce((acc, elem) => ({
        ...acc,
        [elem]: elem
    }), {} as { [Key in Keys[number]]: Key }
    )


// createConstants: <string, ["a", "b", "c"]>
createConstants("a", "b", "c");
```

`Keys` is infered as `["a", "b", "c"]`.

[Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) you can find more information about function arguments inference

P.S. try to avoid mutations in TypeScript, t can lead to weird errors. See [this](https://catchts.com/mutations) article

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a little bit of assertion inside the function, you can do this:

```
const createConstants = <K extends string>(...keys: K[]): {[Key in K]: Key} => {
  let record = {} as {[Key in K]: Key};
  keys.forEach(key => {
    record[key] = key;
  });
  return record;
};

createConstants("a", "b", "c"); // { a: "a"; b: "b"; c: "c";}
```

A `Record` type is presumably not actually useful here since something like `Record<Keys, Keys>` is broader than the return type of the function. You can't match keys to values with a `Record` type.

After some further consideration, a more typesafe version of this would require that the input is of a tuple type. This will prevent false types being returned from inputs like `("a" | "b")[]`, which cannot be guaranteed to have either property present:

```
const createConstants = <K extends string>(...keys: [K, ...K[]): {[Key in K]: Key}

createConstants("a", "b", "c"); // ok

const tuple = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;
createConstants(...tuple) // ok

const undetermined = [] as ("a" | "b")[];
createConstants(...undetermined) // not ok
```

Comment: I'm impressed typescript is actually able to do something like this. I was under the impression that it needed some runtime information to infer something like that

Comment: @smac89 There are limits to this approach, and caveats which the assertion covers up. You have to have string literal types already to hand otherwise you'll just get a string indexed object back. And if you spread in an array like `("a" | "b")[]` you'll get an object type back with both properties filled in, even though theres no guarantee both or even one of them are actually present. In fact, I think I'll add a version which requires a tuple since it will prevent this.

Comment: thanks! I was strugling with Records but this works fine!